# Aligning large text and small text that includes a line break in HTML

Tags: html, typography

I'm currently slicing Illustrator assets from our graphic designer into HTML, and there is one part of the design which I'm not sure how best to represent:

[image]

It's not too hard to imagine using table-based layout for this, e.g.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>TDC <br/> CHANNEL</td>
     <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And change font-size of B until it looks right. But representing this design in HTML really seems to be a challenge of proper typography, and it seems evil to use tables for this. I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: you can use only the display of tables but other tags instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styled and with semantic markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/pXyrd/

```
<dl class="clearfix">
    <dt>TDC<br />Channel</dt>
    <dd>B</dd>
</dl>

dl {
    background: #B5B8BE;
    color:#415987;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding:1.5% 1% 1%;
}
dt {
    clear: left;
    float:left;
    font-size:0.8em;
    line-height:1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

dd {
    float:left;
    font-size:2.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height:1em;
    margin: -0.1em 0 0 0.1em;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about how this works? In particular the clearfix style?

Comment: @jbeard: I included the clearfix class here because it was necessary to get the DL container to fully contain it's children. (If you look at the fiddle and remove the clearfix class, you will see the effect.) Normally a clearfix class would already be included in your global CSS (as you often see in boilerplates, resets and initializers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but you could look into the 'text-indent' property in your CSS (maybe make a class for large text, and then wrap your HTML in `<span class="largeText></span>`. It accepts negative values, so keep that in mind. If you provide more information maybe I can come up with something else.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you could leave the break between TDC and CHANNEL and enclose that in a div, then put the big B in a div use css to do the rest....

or try just using the existing break and put the big B in a span